# Jsoup: How to get the returned Documents url, if a redirection was involved in between request and responce

Tags: java, jsoup, web-crawler

I have a Java web crawler. It is opening this type of urls :

http://jobbank.dk/prefetch_net/s.aspx?c=j&u=/5l/GCyVEQ4dr07BQM6aDvW1I0UefK7VvjHbG5dHDz2P2tCsrbBFYiCBFyAvIdjVnWkl3nwjaUdTp8spu4B9B833lJobgVCKRfM MawPa4AoPK7JvRti4tFFFdmUbtr4LajxRjFH ERBWO7cx43GJ6ColMjDI40vayZSqQ Zl54dK4hqc/nj909Nvb 8Hm9aUmecabYb8Lecyigr3RH/msy NRXW8Le66u2OVepyXyLXHApptPYf2RK42PcqKEawanyjbWAnP8WlT9DaiO/adJ9mEEPIAadtEY/ocN3wSa4=

The final url is different that this, which i guess means that a redirect is involved. I can get and parse the returned Document, but is there any way to get the "final", "real" url too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That URL is not doing a redirect, is returning a page which has this `meta` header

```
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://krb-xjobs.brassring.com/TGWebHost/jobdetails.aspx?PartnerId=30033&amp;SiteID=5635&amp;type=mail&amp;jobId=722158"-->
```

You can see your "final" url there.

You can parse the document for this tag with (for example) `select("meta[http-equiv=refresh]")`

And then parse the `content` attribute.

Summing up:

```
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://jobbank.dk/prefetch_net/s.aspx?c=j&u=/5l/GCyVEQ4dr07BQM6aDvW1I0UefK7VvjHbG5dHDz2P2tCsrbBFYiCBFyAvIdjVnWkl3nwjaUdTp8spu4B9B833lJobgVCKRfM MawPa4AoPK7JvRti4tFFFdmUbtr4LajxRjFH ERBWO7cx43GJ6ColMjDI40vayZSqQ Zl54dK4hqc/nj909Nvb 8Hm9aUmecabYb8Lecyigr3RH/msy NRXW8Le66u2OVepyXyLXHApptPYf2RK42PcqKEawanyjbWAnP8WlT9DaiO/adJ9mEEPIAadtEY/ocN3wSa4=").get();
        Elements select = doc.select("meta[http-equiv=refresh]");
        String content = select.first().attr("content");
        String prefix = "url=";
        String url = content.substring(content.indexOf(prefix) + prefix.length());
        System.out.println(url);
```

Will give you your desired uri:

```
https://krb-xjobs.brassring.com/TGWebHost/jobdetails.aspx?PartnerId=30033&SiteID=5635&type=mail&jobId=722158
```

I hope it will help.